# Onkeyup function from table td to add input validation?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a sudoku project and am stumped by validation, the table code is the same throughout so I'll post a small block of code unless more is needed. What I'm trying to do is get the value from each table data cell in my sudoku, and onkeyup, allow only numbers between 1-9. All other characters will produce an error. Here's what I have so far, my javascript function doesnt seem to be getting any values, and I cant figure out why.

```
    <table class="spuzzle">
    <thead>
    <tr><th></th>



        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>

        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>


        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <td class ="greenBox" rowspan="3" colspan="3">
        <table class="subTable">
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
                <td>4</td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction()"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>


    function myFunction()
    {
    var num = document.getElementsByClassName("subTable").value;
    var num = parseInt(num, 10);
    alert(num);
    if(num < 1 || num > 9){
    document.getElementsByClassName("subTable").value = "";
    alert("Please Enter a Number Between 1 and 9.");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/tu26fnq2/1/)**

Well I suggest you to pass the `element` to the `function` as `parameter` and just check its `innerHTML` as below:

---

**Updated markup**

```
<td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"></td><!-- Pass element with this-->
<td contenteditable="true" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"></td>
<td>4</td>
```

You **JS** then would be as below

```
function myFunction(ctrl)
{
    var num = ctrl.innerHTML; //get its innerHTML
    num = parseInt(num, 10);
    if(num < 1 || num > 9){
        ctrl.innerHTML="";//clear it if num is not what you expect
        alert("Please Enter a Number Between 1 and 9.");
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to check whether the entered character is number or not, just use `isNaN` function as below:

```
function myFunction(ctrl)
{
    var num = ctrl.innerHTML;
    num = parseInt(num, 10);
    if(!isNaN(num))//if num is number then perform check for range
    {
        if(num < 1 || num > 9){
            ctrl.innerHTML="";
            alert("Please Enter a Number Between 1 and 9.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //just clear if any bad characters entered and show alert if needed
        ctrl.innerHTML="";
        alert('Please enter digits only');
    }
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/tu26fnq2/2/)**

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot, mark as answer when time allows.

Comment: Sure.. Happy Coding.. :)